# Error while enabling service broker for my azure sql database

Tags: sql-server

I want to enable service broker for my Microsoft SQL database to use sqldependency.

I tried using the below command:

```
ALTER DATABASE user_details SET ENABLE_BROKER;
```

but it shows an error that I don't have permission to enable it. I myself created the database.

this is the error:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 5 User does not have permission to
>   alter database 'user_details', the database does not exist, or the
>   database is not in a state that allows access checks. Msg 5069, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL Dependency with Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649248/using-sql-dependency-with-azure)

Comment: OT for SO - [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate